# How do I find the hash "market share" of P2Pool?

Tags: mining-pools, p2pool

[P2Pool](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/P2Pool) is a peer to peer mining pool, offering some advantages over centralized pools:

- There is no central node to take down (assuming the pool is indeed fully decentralized). Pools have suffered from DDOS attacks in the past.
- An open source P2P pool should [theoretically be able to operate with zero fees](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/253/how-can-p2pool-charge-a-fee).

How can I find out how many people are using P2Pool?

Comment: As currently phrased, this is fairly localised in time.  What's the enduring question here?

Comment: @eMansipater - "How should I talk to a database in Java" is also time-dependent, but that doesn't mean it's not a good question. I'd like to know the answer now - and if it change, let's change the accepted answer.

Comment: "Is X being adopted?" changes monthly if not daily.  Talking to a database in Java, not so much (but that's still not an amazing question for SO.  Much better would be "How should I talk to a database in Java in the following situation?" or "Which ways of talking to a database in Java meet the following criteria?" etc.)

Comment: @eMansipater - perhaps "How do I find the hash 'market share' of P2Pool?"

Comment: Much better imo.

Comment: You can find a graph showing the hash rate of the pool over time here: http://forre.st:9332/graphs/ (or at http://localhost:9332/graphs/ if you're running p2pool on your own machine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In concept, P2Pool is much stronger than centralized pools. Unfortunately, most centralized pools still hold a high hash-rate.

You can see the global hash rate, and its distribution at http://bitcoinwatch.com/

My opinion is that miners are used to using slush, deep bit, and btcguild - and are either unaware of the incentives of P2Pool, or don't care.

Comment: Is P2Pool cheaper than other pools? Can it be?

Comment: The largest reason miners use the "big 3" is reduced volatility.  Now medium sized pools w/ various "pay per share" methods have reduced that demand somewhat but p2pool is proportional and in proportional pools size matters.

Comment: @ripper234 P2Pool charges a voluntary 0.5% fee, so it's much cheaper than some other pools.  Deepbit charges 10% for example.